# How to find subtract the values corresponding to previous date from the next date in R

Tags: r

The data frame is arranged by date.
I want to subtract the values on the previous date from the ones on the next date and display them.

[This is the previous table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXph8.png)

[This is the resultant table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svSBr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, list( ~ . - lag(.)))
```

---

Or with `diff`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ c(NA, diff(.))))
```